# Select class template specialised for base-class of derived instance

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following example program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Dispatch
{
    static void send(T&) { std::cout << "unknown\n"; }
};

struct Processor
{
    template<typename T>
    void process(T&& t) { Dispatch<T>::send(t); }
};

template<typename T>
struct Base
{};

template<typename T>
struct Dispatch<Base<T>>
{
    static void send(Base<T>&) { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};

struct Deriv : Base<int>
{};

int main()
{
    Processor p;
    p.process(Base<int>{}); // prints "base"
    p.process(Deriv{});     // prints "unknown"
    return 0;
}
```

When calling `Processor::process()` with a `Deriv` instance (which is a `Base` subclass), I would like the `Dispatcher()` specialised for `Base` class templates to be selected.

However, in the example above, the following occurs:

- passing a `Base<T>` instance to `process()` calls the `Base<T>` specialisation
- passing a `Deriv` instance to `process()` calls the primary class  template

**Question:**

- Why is `Base<T>` not a better specialisation for `Deriv` than the primary class template?
- Is there a general way to call the `Base<T>` specialisation when passed `Base<T>` subclasses?

Comment: Well, `Base<T>` specialization does not match to template parameter which is `Deriv`. You can call specialized version explicitly converting type `p.process(static_cast<Base<int> &&>(Deriv{}));`

Comment: You probably want `template<typename T>
    void process(T&& t) { Dispatch<std::decay_t<T>>::send(t); }` else with l-value, you got `Dispatch</*const*/Base<int>&>::send(t)` which also won't match your specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SFINAE, you may do:

```
// Traits to detect inheritance:
template <typename T> std::true_type derive_from_base_impl(Base<T>*);
std::false_type derive_from_base_impl(...);

template <typename T>
using derive_from_base_t = decltype(derive_from_base_impl(std::declval<T*>()));
```

Then some changes

```
template<typename T, typename Enabler = void>
struct Dispatch
{
    static void send(T&) { std::cout << "unknown\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Dispatch<T, std::enable_if_t<derive_from_base_t<T>::value>>
{
    static void send(T&) { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4568dd30d189c11)

Comment: Why not simply `std::is_base_of`?

Comment: @SergeyA: `std::is_base_of<Base<int>, T>` would work, but for general case, we need to also found the template of `Base<U>`.

Comment: So simple and obvious when you show it like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Template specialization works for literally the same type. If you specialized template for `Base`, this specialization will not work for `Derived`.

One way to solve this would be to use partial specialization which you enable for types derived from `Base`.